# Doppler effect derivation related

Tags: special-relativity, frequency, wavelength

In Doppler effect of light the two equations are of frequency and wavelength which looks kinda same so if we substitute in all square roots the $v/c$ part we get

\begin{equation}
  \dfrac{\nu' \text{(emitted)}}{\nu\:\text{(observed)}}=\dfrac{1\!-\!\beta \cos\theta}{\sqrt{1\!-\!\beta^2}} =\dfrac{\lambda\:\text{(observed)}}{\lambda' \text{(emitted)}} \,, \qquad  \beta=\dfrac{v}{c}
\tag{01}\label{eq01} 
\end{equation}

Am I right?

Comment: Possible Duplicate : [Doppler effect equation derivation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/339096/doppler-effect-equation-derivation/357712#357712).

Comment: can this be appllied to real life problems and is this valid if both observer and source are moving

Comment: [Relativistic Doppler effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect)

Comment: i meant if two  objects are moving and one is emitting a radio wave and the other one receives the wave and knows the frequency of the received wave we can calculate the any unknown value in real life situation?