# How do we deal with doppler effect in $3D$ space?

Tags: waves, doppler-effect, applied-physics

In $2D$ it's easy to deal with doppler effect given the velocity of the source and the velocity of the observer like in fig (1) where we have the observer at A static and the source in direction of $\vec{u}$ emitting waves with velocity $v$ and frequency $f$ and moving with velocity $v_s$ we will say that

$$f'=\frac{v}{v-v_s\cos(\theta)}*f$$
Where theta is the angle between the $x$-axis and the $\vec{u}$.

Now if we have have a vector in space with the same frequency and velocity and a static point in space how do we represent the actual frequency $f'$ that the observer receives?

fig (1)
[image]

fig (2)
[image: fig1]

Comment: Related : [Doppler effect equation derivation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/339096/).

Comment: Two vectors define a plane. You have two vectors: The vector from the moving particle to the fixed particle at t=0, and the vector of the moving particle's velocity. You can rotate the 3-D case into the 2-D case. First place the separation vector arbitrarily somewhere in a 2-D surface. Then rotate around this until the velocity is in the same 2-D surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**2D case**
$$\vec R=\begin{bmatrix}
 a-u\,t \\
 b \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
and $~\vec R~$ with polar coordinate

$$\vec R_p=r\,\begin{bmatrix}
 \cos(\phi) \\
 \sin(\phi) \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

with

$$\vec R=\vec R_p\quad \Rightarrow\\
r=\sqrt{b^2+(a-\,t)^2}\quad,
\tan(\phi)=\frac{b}{a-u\,t}\\
v=\dot r=-\frac{u\,(a-u\,t)}{\sqrt{b^2+(a-u\,t)^2}}$$

substitute $~(a-u\,t)=\frac b{\tan(\phi)}~$ in $~v~$ you obtain
$~v=-u\,\cos(\phi)$

$$
f' = \frac{c}{c -u\,\cos(\phi)  } f
$$

**3D case**

$$\vec R=\begin{bmatrix}
  a-u\,t \\
 b \\
  c\\
\end{bmatrix}\quad,
\vec R_p=  r\left[ \begin {array}{c} \cos \left( \phi \right) \sin \left( \theta
 \right) \\  \sin \left( \phi \right) \sin \left( 
\theta \right) \\  \cos \left( \theta \right) 
\end {array} \right] $$

$\vec R=\vec R_p\quad\Rightarrow$

$$r=\sqrt{b^2+(a-u\,t)^2+c^2}\\
\tan(\phi)=\frac{b}{a-u\,t}\\
\tan(\theta)=\frac{\sqrt{b^2+(a-u\,t)^2}}{c}\\
v=\dot r=-\frac{u\,(a-u\,t)}{\sqrt{b^2+(a-u\,t)^2+c^2}}=-u\,\cos(\phi)\,\sin(\theta)
$$

$$
f' = \frac{c}{c -u\,\cos(\phi)\,\sin(\theta)  } f
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $\hat{r}$ is a unit vector pointing from the source to the receiver, then   $v_s \cos \theta = \hat{r} \cdot \vec{v}_s$, where $\vec{v}_s$ is the velocity vector of the source.  So the natural generalization is
$$
f' = \frac{c}{c - \hat{r} \cdot \vec{v}_s} f
$$
which is perfectly well-defined in 3D.