# Proof of de Broglie wavelength for electron

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, wavelength

According to de Broglie's wave-particle duality, the relation between electron's wavelength and momentum is $\lambda =h/mv$.

The proof of this is given in my textbook as follows:

1. De Broglie first used Einstein's famous equation relating matter and energy,
   $$E=mc^2,$$
   where $E=$ energy, $m =$ mass, $c =$ speed of light.
2. Using Planck's theory which states every quantum of a wave has a discrete amount of energy given by Planck's equation,
   $$E=h\nu,$$
   where $E =$ energy, $h =$ Plank's constant ($6.62607 \times 10^{-34}\:\mathrm{ J\:s}$), $\nu =$ frequency.
3. Since de Broglie believes particles and wave have the same traits, the two energies would be the same:
   $$mc^2=h\nu.$$
4. Because real particles do not travel at the speed of light, de Broglie substituted $v$, velocity, for $c$, the speed of light:
   $$mv^2=h\nu.$$

I want a direct proof without substituting $v$ for $c$. Is it possible to prove directly $\lambda=h/mv$ without substituting $v$ for $c$ in the equation $\lambda =h/mc$?

Comment: This doesn't actually prove what you're stating. Which textbook is this?

Comment: Direct proof starting with what axioms?   One could take the de Broglie relationship as an axiom.

Comment: Related : [About de Broglie relations, what exactly is  E ? Its energy of what?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/257826/).

Answer (score 3):

The $c$ in $mc^2$ is not the actual speed of the particle (unless we’re talking about light, but then m would be zero). $mc^2$ is simply the energy the particle has at rest.
I don’t know exactly how De Broglie did it, but you can prove it like this:

First you can prove that the momentum operator should be $\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$ by finding the generator of the translation operator in the quantum mechanical way (which gives you something like $\frac{d}{dx}$ as the generator) and the classical way (which gives you the momentum as the generator), and simply state that both results should be equivalent.
If this sounds unfamiliar, then I suggest you look into Noether’s theorem (it’s one of the coolest theorem’s in maths/physics, so I would suggest it anyway).
But if you’re okay with just assuming that the momentum operator is equal to $\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$, then you can just start from there.

Using $p = \frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$ and the assumption that particles have a wave-like nature, you can prove that $p = \frac{h}{λ}$. Since in general, we can write the wave function of a given state of a particle as: $Ψ(x,t) = Ψ_0 e^{i(kx-ωt)}$, which gives us: $pΨ = \frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{dΨ}{dx} = \hbar k Ψ$, so $p = \hbar k = h/λ$.

You can do the same thing to prove Planck’s theorem by first finding the generator of time translation and prove that the operator of energy should be $i \hbar \frac{d}{dt}$, and then letting this operator act on $Ψ$ again.

N.B.: In the most general case $Ψ(x,t)$ should be a superposition of wave functions with different $Ψ_0$, $k$ and/or $ω$, but then you can’t be sure what the momentum of your particle is anymore.

Comment: Please refer to this link for learning how to format math in your question: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks, this was my first comment here, and I was a bit too lazy to look up how to write the math properly. It’s basically latex, right?

Answer (score 3):

De Broglie proposed that the relation $p=h/\lambda$ would not only hold for photons but also for massive particles. This inspired Schrödinger to propose his famous equation.

Answer (score 2):

The "proof" on the question is incorrect since it claims that the energy of the matter wave is $E=mv^2$, which is double of what it really is.

Here, I am going to demonstrate the non-relativistic case. For relativistic case, one **can not prove** de Broglie's hypothesis, it should be a postulate, just like Planck's hypothesis. Actually in relativistic QM, the postulate is in terms of a four-vector: $p^\mu = \hbar k^\mu$, where $p^\mu=(E/c, \mathbf{p})$ is four-momentum and $k^\mu = (\omega/c, \mathbf{k})$ is the wave four-vector.

---

The group velocity for any wave is as follows:
$$
v_g = \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial k}
$$
where $\omega$ and $k$ are angular frequency and wave number, respevtively. We use Planck's hypothesis, $E=\hbar \omega$, where $E$ is the kinetic energy of a particle for **non-relativistic** case:
$$
\hbar \omega = \frac{p^2}{2m}
$$
where $p$ is the momentum and $m$ is the mass of the matter wave.

Since the group velocity corresponds to the actual velocity of the wave packet, then
$$
v = \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial k} = \frac{1}{2m \hbar} \frac{\partial p^2}{\partial k} = \frac{p}{m \hbar} \frac{\partial p}{\partial k}
$$
If you multiply both sides by $m \hbar$, then
$$
\hbar mv =  p\frac{\partial p}{\partial k} \\
\hbar p = p\frac{\partial p}{\partial k} \\
\hbar =  \frac{\partial p}{\partial k}
$$
Therefore the momentum should be proportional to the wave number:
$$
p = \hbar k
$$
QED.

Comment: "which is double of what it really is" More precisely, twice the total minus rest energy for the non-relativistic case.

Comment: There is no rest energy in non-relativistic case. So, your statement is maybe *overprecise* :)

Comment: Your statement is a _contradictio in terminis_. @Oktay

Comment: OK. Why is that?

Comment: Rest energy is the energy of a system at rest, which is the extreme non-relativistic case. The Schrödinger equation does not contain the rest energy, because for non-relativistic energy differences it is unnecessary. This does not mean that a non-relativistic electron does not have a rest energy.

Comment: $mc^2$ is a contribution at comparable relativistic energies, not the limits. On the other hand, the rest energy of a particle is not measurable in non-relativistic physics (there are only energy differences), and not renormalizable to an absolute value, since when you take the non-relativistic limit, the energy would be infinite. So, we only talk about the kinetic energy here.

Comment: So now we cannot weigh an electron anymore? I dis it myself during my physics studies using a circular discharge in a bulb. And, really, are there are only energy differences in non-relativistic physics? Earth has no rest energy ? What keeps it in its orbit? Who taught you this stuff? @Oktay

Comment: "Weighing" an electron in non-relativistic physics is only possible in the case of an acceleration (e/m experiment, gravity (in principle), etc.) or a collusion. The mass is not a form of energy in non-relativistic physics (see: mass vs energy conservation). You can even construct a Lorentzian-like description for Galilean mechanics where there is a fifth dimension for mass (See: M. de Montigny *et al.*, "Poincaré Gauge Theory and Galilean Covariance", Annals Phys. 277 (1999) 144-158)

Comment: You should know that only general relativity has a physical concept of absolute energy (i.e., the cosmological constant), all other theories can only talk about energy differences. By the way, I didn't like your attitude rejecting everything I have explained with arrogance. Have a nice day!

Comment: To me non-relativistic physics is just relativistic physics with things moving slowly or even at rest. $E=mc^2$ would is of course also valid when things go slow.

Comment: The statement "There is no rest energy in non-relativistic case. " to me is a contradiction. I don't know how to soften this message. Otherwise have a very nice evening !