# Why do we replace $c$ (speed of light) with $v$ in de Broglie's equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, speed-of-light, mass-energy, wavelength, wave-particle-duality

Deriving de Broglie's equation (as per my text and teacher) involves equating $E = mc^2$ with $E = h\nu$, where $\nu$ is the frequency.
It goes like :

$$mc^2 = h\nu$$
$$mc^2 = \frac{hc}{\lambda}$$
$$mc = \frac{h}{\lambda}.$$

Then we replace $c$ with the velocity of the particle to apply it generally

i.e. $$mv = \frac{h}{\lambda}.$$

My doubt is exactly about this step. As far as I have read before and after learning this equation, I understood that $c$ in $E = mc^2$ was mainly used as a constant which can equate energy and mass rather than something relating energy, mass and velocity of the particle. Thus replacing $c$ with $v$ makes no sense as it would have contradicted the equivalence of $E=mc^2$ in the first place.

Can someone explain how $c$ can be replaced with $v$ without contradicting $E = mc^2$, or just simply point out what is wrong with my thought process?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof of de Broglie wavelength for electron](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/349372/)

Comment: Related : [About de Broglie relations, what exactly is  E ? Its energy of what?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/257826/).

Comment: I had already read about that question in my doubt clearing journey; The problem that I found was that the author was trying to avoid the alleged contradiction by using another way around the proof. I wanted to know whether my reasoning was correct or I was making a grave mistake. So all in all it does not serve my real purpose. Thank you for the suggestion !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I see this is your first post here and if you intend on keeping your contributions to the forum, I suggest you read this [link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn about MathJax.

Second of all, I see the problem you're having here. The famous equation which relates wave-like properties such as the wavelength $\lambda$ and a mechanical property (present to all objects), the momentum, $p$, wasn't really derived from the energy-mass equivalence $$E=mc^2$$

In fact, you have two fundamental relations, called the De-Broglie-Einstein relations which state
$$E=h\nu \ ; \ \lambda=\frac{h}{p}$$
where as you should know, $h$ is the Planck's constant. These are rather general formulas, and at first De-Broglie was criticized (by his thesis evaluators) that his idea of everything having a related wavelength was original, but sounded "magical". Actually, the energy-mass equivalence in the way I wrote it shall only be used for particles at rest, the "complete" formula is
$$E=\sqrt{m^2c^4+p^2c^2}$$
so that it reduces to the above one when the particle has null velocity. Coming back to the De-Broglie-Einstein relations, you can substitute $p$ for whatever expression you have for your system. For non-relativistic, "normal" systems, the usual expression is $p=mv$ where $v$ is the speed of the particle.

I hope this clears your question a bit.

Comment: So does this mean that $E = mc^2$ can't actually be used for proving de Broglie's equation as it involves a particle having velocity? Thank you for the suggestion about mathjax.

Comment: I don't know if this is your situation, but usually in high school you use $E=mc^2$ for this proof because it is intuitive, but yes. It's not entirely correct. This formula is only valid for particles at rest.