# How is the equation for de Broglie wavelength actually derived?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavelength, wave-particle-duality

I have seen the equation for de Broglie wavelength derived through equating Einstein's $E=mc^{2}$, and Planck's $E=hf$, using a substitution from $c=f\lambda$ to make things in terms of wavelength. From this the following result is derived:
$$ \lambda = \frac{h}{mc} $$
This makes sense to me under the assumption that such a wavelength exists. However, at this point a substitution is made for $c$ changing it to $v$. How is this valid? The speed of light is a specific velocity and in the case of Einstein's mass energy equivalence is important that it is such, and not just any velocity. Is there a good reason for this? And if not and this is just meant to be a dumbed down version to give to high school students, does anyone have a correct way of arriving at the desired result?

Comment: Does this help? [Proof of the de Broglie wavelength for electron.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/349372/)

Comment: You could read it from the man himself, to really go deeper, amazing how he brought such insight just with his PhD thesis:
http://aflb.ensmp.fr/LDB-oeuvres/De_Broglie_Kracklauer.pdf

Comment: Related : [About de Broglie relations, what exactly is E? It's energy of what?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257826/about-de-broglie-relations-what-exactly-is-e-its-energy-of-what/258207#258207).