# De broglie from other reference frame

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, inertial-frames

From de Broglie hypothesis we know that for a particle with Momentum p,
Wavelength(L)

$$L=h/p$$

Now suppose we look at the same particle from another reference frame, so the momentum P gets changed and if this law is to be conserved then the wavelength also has to be changed but this is absurd as wavelength is not dependent not reference frame.
So,where lies the fallacy?

Comment: When you are familiar with 4-vectors, first steps of Special Relativity and Lorentz Transformation take a look in my answer therein : [About de Broglie relations, what exactly is E? Its energy of what?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257826/about-de-broglie-relations-what-exactly-is-e-its-energy-of-what/258207#258207)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on whether we are dealing with relativistic systems or not.  The answer by Arthur refers to the relativistic case where the wavelength changes because of Lorentz contraction.  In my opinion the  non-relativistic case of Schroedinger waves is rather more interesting because what happens is quite subtle.  Suppose  we have a solution $\psi(x,t)$ to the Schroedinger equation
$$
i\hbar\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} = -\frac {\hbar^2}{2m}
\frac {\partial^2\tilde \psi }{\partial x^2} + V(x)\psi, 
$$
and look at it from a moving frame where the equation becomes 
$$
i\hbar\frac{\partial \tilde\psi}{\partial t} = -\frac {\hbar^2}{2m}
\frac {\partial^2\tilde \psi }{\partial x^2} + V(x-Ut)\tilde\psi. 
$$
Then  some manipuations with the chain-rule for partial derivatives shows that we must have 
$$
\tilde \psi(x,t)= e^{imUx/\hbar -i\frac 12
mU^2t/\hbar}\psi(x-Ut,t).
$$
The extra phases  mean that quantum wavefunctions do not transform as scalars under Galilean transformations.  For example the wavefunction for an electron in the ground state of a hydrogen atom is a real function, but seen by someone running  at speed $U$ towards  the atom, the electron has a net momentum $p=mU$ towards the runner and the wavefunction   has an $e^{-imU/\hbar}$ factor.

How this arises is quiate  interesting. To get the non-relativistic wavefunction $\psi(x,t)$ for a particle of mass $m$ from a relativistic wavefunction  $\phi(x,t)$ that *does* transform as a scalar, we write
$$
\phi(x,t)= e^{-imc^2 t/\hbar}\psi(x,t).
$$
In other words the non-relativistic $\psi$ does  not  include the phase coming from the $mc^2$ rest-mass energy.
Suppose now  we make a Lorentz transform
$$
x\to x'= (x-Ut)/\sqrt{1-U^2/c^2},
$$
$$
t\to t' = (t+Ux/c^2)/\sqrt{1-U^2/c^2}.
$$
Even when  $U$ is very  small compared to $c$ --- so that we are effectively  making a Galilean transform --- 
the $c^2$ in the $mc^2$ cancels with the $c^2$ in the $x/c^2$ term and the result is the extra factor of  $e^{imUx/\hbar}$ in $\tilde \psi$.

I first learned all this from a problem at the end of Chapter 22 in Gordon Baym's "Lectures on Quantum Mechanics."

Answer (score 2):

Using $\lambda=\frac{h}{p}$ and $\omega=\frac{E}{\hbar}$ we can write the following relations:
$$\tag{1}\vec{p}=\hbar\vec{k}\label{1}$$
$$\tag{2}E=\hbar\omega\label{2}$$
In general, the four-momentum is:
$$P=\left(\frac{E}{c},\vec{p}\right)$$
Using (\ref{1}) and (\ref{2}):
$$P=\left(\frac{\hbar\omega}{c},\hbar\vec{k}\right)$$
We can define the four wave-vector $K$ as:
$$K=\left(\frac{\omega}{c},\vec{k}\right)$$
So the four-momentum becomes:
$$P=\hbar K$$
All the four-vectors are frame-independent.

Comment: I'm afraid,I am not yet familiar with four momentum.Could you please illaborate in some easier,i mean,physical way?

Comment: The wavelength **is** frame dependent. In some frame of reference the particle has $(p,\lambda)$ and in another frame of reference it has different momentum and different wavelength $(p’,\lambda’)$. But they combine in such a way that the energy-momentum is conserved. Consider a particle that has energy $E$ and momentum $p$ in some inertial frame, it will have different set of energy-momentum in another inertial frame, but they will always combine in such a way that the energy and momentum is conserved.

Comment: @user157588 Griffiths has nice introductions to four-vectors in 'Introduction to Elementary Particles' and 'Introduction to Electrodynamics'.