Relation between dual nature and mass
Just read the topic of dual nature of matter especially of light.
one of our lecturers said that not just light but every particle of matter exhibits dual nature
and he also said that it depends on mass.
it will be helpful is anyone provides the mathematical notation of this statement.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/800402

The mathematical formula is the De Broglie wave length =ℎ/|⃗ | with |⃗ |=m*v
