# The special relativity with wave equation

Tags: special-relativity, wave-particle-duality

With the formation of Einstein special relativity, $E^2 = p^2c^2 + m^2c^4$, could the term of mass be replaced with the De Broglie equation of material waves while $p$, momentum, be replaced with the momentum of the wave as $hk$ where $k$ is the wavenumbers?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein-Gordon_equation#Derivation

Comment: Thank you for the respond, I know that; but if the momentum could be written as hk, and mass could be written as h/v(lambda), will it be the energy of the waves from the special relativity?

Comment: $p=\hbar k$ is same as de Broglie relation, 
$$p=\frac{h}{\lambda}$$
since $k=\frac{2 \pi}{\lambda}$ and $\hbar = 2\pi/h $. Probably you meant Compton wavelength, $\lambda_C = \frac{h}{mc}$?? If so, do not forget that Compton wavelength is not the wavelength of the particle, it is instead the wavelength of the photon that scatters from it due to its mass.

Comment: I meant matter-wave directly, not Compton wavelength. If I use hk to replace the momentum for waves, h/v(lambda) to replace the mass; the special relativity will be $E^2 = h^2k^2c^2 + (h/v(lambda))^2c^4$. What would this energy mean? Moreover, by simple substitution, this term of energy will contain the energy of photon from photoelectric effect as well.

Comment: "[C]ould the term of mass be replaced with the De Broglie equation of material waves[?]" -- How do you replace a real number (i.e., mass) with an equation (i.e., the De Broglie equation)? It is unclear as to what you mean. Voting to close.

Comment: I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave#Special_relativity) might help you somewhat.

Comment: Related : [About de Broglie relations, what exactly is  E ? Its energy of what?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257826/about-de-broglie-relations-what-exactly-is-e-its-energy-of-what/258207#258207).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that because it's the wrong "mass". The $m$ in the formula for $E^2$ is rest mass, not relativistic mass.

Comment: You meant the m in the special relativity was the rest mass? But how about that momentum term, $ E = mc^2$ was for the rest mass. But when De Broglie used $ E = mc^2$ for the rest mass and $ E = hv$ for photoelectric effect, they could work.

Comment: @B.D. No, $E=mc^2$ uses the relativistic mass, which is why it's consistent with the rest-mass-using equation you quoted.

Comment: Since the De Broglie equation was from the process of derivation of special relativity and photoelectric effect equation, will the energy of the matter wave from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave be compatible with the energy term from the special relativity with the momentum term $ p^2c^2$ ?

Comment: @B.D. You need $E=h\nu=\hbar\omega$.

Comment: @ J.G. could $ E = hv $ be compatible for the energy waves? Wasn't it only served for the photon energy? Could $ E = hv $ work for the matter wave as well?

Comment: @B.D. Yes, it would.

Comment: since it would work for the matter wave, could it, $ E=hv $ be used as an energy operator for the hamiltonian as well?