# De Broglie relation using four momentum in particle physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, particle-physics, momentum

In particle phyisics four-momentum is used and De Broglie relation is used to understand what lenghts can be "seen" in an experiment.

[Here (page 6)](https://people.phys.ethz.ch/~pheno/PPP/PPP2.pdf) it is claimed

> The key factor for investigating the proton substructure is the wavelength of the probing
>   photon, which is related to the transferred momentum by
>   $$\lambda\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{Q^2}}$$

Where $Q^2$ is not actually "momentum" but its the square of the four momentum transferred by the photon.

I can't understand why this is used, since the square root of  square of four momentum is

$$\sqrt{p\cdot p}=\sqrt{|\textbf{p}|^2-E^2/c^2}$$

While De Broglie relation usually involves the three momentum $\textbf{p}$
$$\lambda\sim \frac{1}{|\textbf{p}|}$$

So is in this case $\sqrt{Q^2}$ approximately the three momentum? Or is the De Broglie relation in the relativistic case to be written using $\sqrt{Q^2}$ instead of three momentum?

Comment: Related  :  [About de Broglie relations, what exactly is E? Its energy of what?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257826/about-de-broglie-relations-what-exactly-is-e-its-energy-of-what/258207#258207).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In scattering experiments, specifically electron scattering, the four momentum of the virtual photon is:

$$ q_{\mu} = k_{\mu}-k'_{\mu}$$

where $k_{\mu}$ and $k'_{\mu}$ are the (on shell) initial and final electron momenta, respectively.

It is traditional to look at the process in the Breit Frame (also called the brick wall frame): this is frame where the electron bounces 180 degrees elastically off the target, so that:

$$ k_{\mu} = (E, \vec p) $$

and

$$ k'_{\mu} = (E, -\vec p) $$

Hence:

$$ q_{\mu} = (0, \vec q) = (0, 2\vec p) $$

There is no energy transfer, and $q_{\mu}$ is entirely space-like.

In some sense, this is the frame where the photon can be seen as "most virtual", as it has lots of 3 momentum and no energy. Nevertheless, $Q^2$ is invariant, so you can evaluate it:

$$ -Q^2 = 4p^2 \approx 4EE'\sin^2{\frac{\theta} 2}$$

where the last expression is evaluated in the lab with $E>>m_e$.

It is in the Breit frame the $-\sqrt{Q^2}=||\vec q|| \propto 1/\lambda \ $ clearly defines the wavelength; moreover, the initial and final state plane waves are coupled by the transition element:

$$ T(q) \propto \int{(e^{-ipx}\ )^*\rho(x)e^{+ipx}\ d^3x} = \int{e^{iqx}\ \rho(x)d^3x}$$

which is the Fourier transform of the charge distribution--thus a scattering event with $Q^2$ is sensitive to structure on the scale of $1/\sqrt{-Q^2}$.