# Is the de Broglie formula normalized for relativity?

Tags: relativity, wave-particle-duality

The de Broglie formula is normally given as:
$\lambda=h/mv$.
Does this hold for velocity near the speed of light?  In this case would you use the rest mass or relativistic mass?

Comment: Related : [About de Broglie relations, what exactly is  E ? Its energy of what?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/257826/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The de Broglie wavelenght comes from assuming massive particles have the same relations as the photon:

$$
E=\frac{hc}{\lambda}=pc,
$$

so that
$$
\lambda_B =\frac{h}{p}=\frac{h}{\gamma mv}=\frac{h}{mv}\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}},
$$

which reduces to the usual $\frac{h}{mv}$ in the non-relativistic limit ($c\to\infty$).