# Confusion regarding an exercise problem in SR

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

Following is an exercise question from Relativity SPECIAL, GENERAL, AND
COSMOLOGICAL
SECOND EDITION, Wolfgang Rindler

> 2.6. Consider the usual two inertial frames S and S' in standard configuration. In S' the standard lattice clocks all emit a ‘flash’ at noon. Prove that in S this flash occurs
>   on a plane orthogonal to the x-axis and traveling in the positive x-direction at (de
>   Broglie) speed $c^2/v$.

1. I assume that the flashes are of light which means that they should be travelling at the speed of light, so I don't understand how to prove it to be $c^2/v$.
2. Again I assume that v here is the velocity of the reference frame S' with respect to S. Is it correct?

Can someone just explain what the question wants me to do?

Comment: Please use superscripts to make your question clear.

Comment: Don’t expect readers to figure out what $c2$ is supposed to mean.

Comment: Just forget about the "(de Broglie)" and it's a normal exercise in special relativity.

Comment: @knzhou So does it mean that the flash is travelling at $c^2/v$ is what we have to prove?

Comment: Related : [About de Broglie relations, what exactly is  E ? Its energy of what?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257826/about-de-broglie-relations-what-exactly-is-e-its-energy-of-what/258207#25820).

Comment: What the question wants you to do is prove that in S this flash occurs on a plane orthogonal to the x-axis and traveling in the positive x-direction at (de Broglie) speed $c^2/v$.