# De-Broglie equation for other particles except photon

Tags: quantum-mechanics

If E=hf is applicable for electron and other particles, the De Broglie wavelength should be λ=hv/pc. Because, mc^2=hf which implies mc^2=hc/λ which implies m=h/λc and thus λ=hv/pc. But I have found in my text book that λ=h/p is applicable not only for photon but also for all particle. But how can λ=h/p=h/mv be applicable for all particle?

Comment: Related : [About de Broglie relations, what exactly is  E ? Its energy of what?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257826/about-de-broglie-relations-what-exactly-is-e-its-energy-of-what/258207#258207).

Comment: This video from 3blue1brown has a section on this. [The more general uncertainty principle, beyond quantum](https://www.3blue1brown.com/videos-blog/2018/2/25/uncertainty-principle-its-not-about-quantum)

Answer (score 2):

The De Broglie relations
$$
E=h\nu, p=\frac{h}{\lambda}
$$
are applicable to all particles.
However the relation between the frequency/energy and the wave length/momentum, is not the same. Thus, for photons $f=\frac{c}{\lambda}$, for non-relativistic electrons $E=\frac{p^2}{2m}$, for relativistic electrons $E^2=m^2c^4 + p^2c^2$.

Answer (score 0):

For your last step you just introduce a v in both the numerator and denominator. That is meaningless as it is unity.

In the expression $\lambda = \frac{h}{mc}$, you just have to set $c=v$ to account for particles with different momenta and thus different velocities, not equal to the speed of light.

Do it in this way:

$$E = hf = mc^2 $$
$$\frac{hc}{\lambda} = mc^2$$
$$\frac{h}{\lambda} = mc$$
$$\lambda = \frac{h}{mc}$$
$$\lambda = \frac{h}{mv}$$

Comment: I have found λ=h/mv in some text books. Isn't it incorrect?

Comment: No, it is correct, check the derivation.

Comment: But why and how have you put v in the last line?

Comment: Because not all particles move at the speed of light c, so you can set c=v to account for particles with different moments and so different velocity.

Comment: You clearly asked about the De Broglie wavelength for particles other than photons. So I repeat, not all particles move at the speed of light.