# Particle spin and frequency

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, frequency

Does the quantum spin of a particle relate to its frequency and wavelength? I cannot seem to find anything on this. If I were to guess, it seems that as $E = hf$, and $\omega = 2\pi f$, and $spin_1 = h/2\pi$, then $E/\omega = spin_1$.

Regards, Pete.

Comment: Related : [About de Broglie relations, what exactly is  E ? Its energy of what?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257826/about-de-broglie-relations-what-exactly-is-e-its-energy-of-what/258207#258207).

Answer (score 4):

No. A photon always has spin $1$ regardless of its wavelength, frequency or energy. An electron always has spin $\pm \frac 1 2$. You are confusing two different uses of the term frequency.

Comment: I seek to understand the wave/particle duality. If calculating the frequency of a particle from its quantum spin of h/2pi and the frequency of its wave from E = hf gives the same answer, then what two different uses of the term frequency have occurred?

Comment: @PeteCarroll In $\omega=2 \pi f$, $\omega$ is angular velocity and $f$ is frequency of rotation. This frequency has nothing to do with the frequency of light, since a photon is not rotating (even though it has quantum spin).