# Properties of matter waves

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, velocity

Can anyone explain me the meaning of this line?
"Velocity of matter wave depends on velocity of particle generating it"

Comment: What is the source of your quote?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave#Group_velocity

Comment: Related : [About de Broglie relations, what exactly is  E ? Its energy of what?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257826/about-de-broglie-relations-what-exactly-is-e-its-energy-of-what/258207#258207).

Comment: A professor of my college stuck this in my head .