# Phase of a wave in relativity

Tags: special-relativity, waves, inertial-frames

Take a one-dimensional plane wave $\exp(i(kx-\omega t))$. How can I show that its phase is a $Lorentz \ Invariant$? How to derive the form of $4-wavevector$?

Comment: Welcome to PSE. If your question concerns plane phase wave in general (for example not electromagnetic or sound wave etc) then it's not the right one. Since a plane phase wave could be "superluminal" so not carrying an interaction. IMO, having a general plane phase wave you consider that its phase is Lorentz invariant and the right question is how this wave is Lorentz tranformed between inertial frames. All these are basic in the theory of de Broglie...

Comment: ... see my answer here [About de Broglie relations, what exactly is E? Its energy of what?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257826/about-de-broglie-relations-what-exactly-is-e-its-energy-of-what/258207#258207)

Answer (score 1):

Actually the phase is exactly $\vec{p}\cdot \vec{x} = \eta(\vec{p}, \vec{x}) = \eta_{\alpha\beta}p^\alpha x^\beta = -\omega t+k_xx+k_yy+k_zz$ where $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{p}$ are 4-vectors in Minkowski space:

$$ \vec{x} = \pmatrix{t \\ x \\ y \\ z},\ \vec{p} = \pmatrix{\omega \\ k_x \\ k_y\\ k_z}$$
But because a dot product of two vectors is Lorentz Invariant the phase is invariant.

Comment: Please elaborate the answer.

Comment: To make this argument work you first need to show that $\omega$ and $\bf k$ are the components of a 4-vector.

Comment: Snpr What is not clear? Andrew I defined these 2-vectors like that, Minkowski space is just $R^n$ with a metric signature -1 1 ... 1.

Comment: Why do you bring in a 1+1 dimensional Minkowski space. Just stick to 1+3 and keep it simple.

Comment: I would prefer to write $ct$ and $\omega/c$ in the 4-vectors, instead of $t$ and $\omega$, to make all 4 components having the same unit.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch They have the same units, in GR we use geometric units.

Comment: In order to show that properties of a wave ($k$ and $\omega$) form parts of a 4-vector, you need to show they transform the right way. You can do this by thinking about wave motion from first principles, but the most direct route is to consider what phase of an oscillation means, and argue that it must be Lorentz invariant. Then the wave-4-vector can be derived as the gradient of the phase. The logic is this way round.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proof not very rigourous. Just to give a slight Idea.

Conservation of Energy momentum four vector $(E/c, p_x, p_y, p_z)$ in STR is given by

$$ p_x^2 + p_y^2 + p_z^2-\frac{E^2}{c^2}=const$$

you can see the proof of this on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-momentum#:%7E:text=Conservation%20of%20four%2Dmomentum%20gives,must%20be%20equal%20to%20M.)  done using $ Action Principle$

Now we Know that $E= \hbar w$ and $p =\hbar k$, and substituting these
$$ (k_x^2 + k_y^2 + k_z^2-\frac{w^2}{c^2} )\hbar=const$$
and this implies
$$ k_x^2 + k_y^2 + k_z^2-\frac{w^2}{c^2} =const$$
So,
$$ \pmatrix{\omega/c \\ k_x \\ k_y\\ k_z} $$
becomes Lorentz Invariant

Comment: You have brought in quantum mechanics, which is ok, but it is better to try to show the result within classical (not quantum) relativity. It can be done by arguing from first principles (i.e. just thinking about what phase means) that the phase must be an invariant.

Comment: the expression which I have Used is correct both in classical as well as quantum domain.But Yes, It should be done using Action Principle