# Difference between de Broglie wavelength and electromagnetic wavelength?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavelength, wave-particle-duality

So we have to find the ratio of wavelength of electrons in 1st and 4th orbit of an atom. Why do we have to use de Broglie wavelength and not $E = \frac{h c}{\lambda}$ ?

Comment: What is the lambda associated with an electron?

Comment: The electrons in a hydrogen atom do not have a wavelength as their wavefunction is not a plane wave. Presumably this is using the Bohr model and calculating the wavelength the electrons would have if the Bohr model were an accurate description. Anyhow, the relationship E = hc/λ only applies to massless particles, while the de Broglie equation λ = h/p applies to all particles massive or otherwise.

Comment: Related : [About de Broglie relations, what exactly is E? Its energy of what?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257826/about-de-broglie-relations-what-exactly-is-e-its-energy-of-what/258207#258207).

Answer (score 0):

The equation $$E = \frac{hc}{\lambda}$$ applies only to particles with no invariant mass (like photons), where $f = \frac{E}{h} =\frac{c}{\lambda}$.

For particles with a non-zero mass (like electrons), the following relations hold: $$\lambda = \frac{h}{p} = \frac{h}{\gamma mu}$$
$$f = \frac{E}{h} = \frac{\gamma mc^2}{h}$$
where $\gamma$ is the Lorentz factor.

Hope this helps.