# What exactly is matter wave?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavelength, wave-particle-duality

Wavelength of matter wave is given by de-broglie as h/p. I want to know wavelength of what wave is being discussed, or specifically what is matter wave? Is it the 'group wave' that has same velocity as the particle or it is the phase wave. But i know that different phase waves have different wavelengths so they probabaly couldn't be matter waves.

Please give a detailed answer to explain everything, this has been bothering me for many days now

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/745221/247642